# UpdateRegistry compilattion error

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, atl

I am getting the following errors when I build an ATL com with the WInCE device SDK provided by the customer. How can I resolve this issue? I created the workspace with the VS-2005.

```
1>f:\polycold\testapps\polycoldsmartdevice\polycoldsmartdevice\CmdParser.h(73) : error C2039: 'UpdateRegistry' : is not a member of 'CCmdParser'
1>        f:\polycold\testapps\polycoldsmartdevice\polycoldsmartdevice\CmdParser.h(29) : see declaration of 'CCmdParser'
1>f:\polycold\testapps\polycoldsmartdevice\polycoldsmartdevice\CmdParser.h(73) : error C2065: 'UpdateRegistry' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Care to share the code?  It's difficult-for me anyway-to determine what is wrong with code I can't read.  I mean you're obiously calling UpdateRegistry, but what is that, and where is it?  It's not a Win32 API.

Comment: Is CmdParser a new ATL object you created using this SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing a lot of guessing with my crystal ball I will asume that CmdParser is a new ATL COM class you are trying to create. If this is the case, I believe there is a bug in VS ATL wizard that makes WINCE ATL projects not valid. An easy workaround I use for this is to comment out the following:

```
//#ifndef _CE_DCOM
DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_TESTATLOBJ)
//#endif
```

You should have a similar code on the header file of your ATL class.

There are some comments on this issue in [this post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/WindowsCE-App-Development/36093629/atl-component-class-not-registered-error.aspx).

Comment: If someone else (@ctacke for example) can put some light on this mistery I will really appreaciate it.

Comment: Your crystal ball is better than mine - I'd not even divined as much info as you. +1 for the attempt.

Comment: @ctacke Thanks. I had the same issue not too long ago, so I was kind of "synchronized"

Comment: @yms: Thanks. It removed the compilation error. Now I am getting the link error LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "commctrl.lib". I cannot find the lib file in the lib folder of the installed sdk. How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Take a look at this post for your new issue: http://www.pocketpcjunkies.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/wince-pb/8517/How-to-remove-errant-library-reference-COMMCTRL-from-my-platform

Comment: @maanu: use an SDK that represents to actual OS you're using or stop using features not present (like common controls).

Comment: As ctacke said, you need to remove the reference to common controls. I guess this was added by the ATL wizard, but you need to remove it if is not available on your SDK.